# How do I add a 'validator' class to this code to get it to work?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

This is the error that I keep receiving: Reflection Exception Class validator does not exist  This is the code causing the problems:

```
  use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

 class DeskServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register bindings
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->repositories();

    $this->app->bind('Desk\Forms\MessageForm', function($app) {
        $validator = $app->make('validator')->make([], []);
        return new \Desk\Forms\MessageForm($validator);
    });
}
}
```

I now know that I need to add a Validator class but I am not sure where or what to put in it.  Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, as is your code.  If looks like you're trying to bind a service.

```
$this->app->bind('Desk\Forms\MessageForm'
```

However, instead of telling Laravel the service name you want to use to identify your service (like `db`, or `message_form`, etc.) you're passing it a class name (`Desk\Forms\MessageForm`).

Then, you're using the application's `make` factory to instantiate a `validator` object.  It's not clear if you're trying to use `make` to instantiate an object from a class named `Validator`, or if you're trying to instantiate a service object from a service named `validator`.  If the later, it doesn't look like a `validator` service exists in your application.  If the former, it doesn't look like a class named `Validator` is defined anywhere Laravel can autoload from.

Regarding the next obvious question: Where can Laravel autoload from, you either want this `Validator` class in your composer package's `src` folder, named in a way that's PSR valid.  If you're not using composer and this is a local application, the easiest thing to do is drop the file in

```
app/models/Validator.php
```

**However**, it's also not clear from your question if you're trying to use the Laravel built-in [Validator service facade/object](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation).  A better question might yield a better answer. (possibly of interest, and a self link, I'm in the middle of writing a series of articles that explains [the Laravel application container](http://alanstorm.com/category/laravel#container), which you may find useful.).

Comment: I added app/models/Validator.php and still getting the error but thanks.